# Why can I not reuse the name of Apex classes deleted in previous releases?

Tags: apex, managed-package, class, isv, ideas

Because the [documentation defines it that way](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/isv_viewing_deleted_components.htm). Yes since Winter'15 it explicitly states:

> Although a component is deleted, its Name remains within Salesforce.
>   You can never create another component with the same name. The `Deleted
>   Package Components` page lists which names can no longer be used.

and

> If the Managed - ReleasedManaged - Released package hasn't been
>   uploaded with the component deleted, this contains an Undelete link
>   that allows you to retrieve the component.

I don't understand why this is needed and it's really bugging me as extensive class renaming (a good refactoring practice) leads to all the good words being unusable after a while. Just an example:

I am naming my Domain classes (per object trigger handlers) as the plural of the SObject. In one of the last releases of our ISV software we got rid of the need to handle trigger events and so I thought I could also get rid of the now empty trigger class. Doing that I lost one of the most self-speaking and most suitable class names for the whole software :-(

1. The whole reason for this question is to hear from someone a good
   explanation why it is not possible to just reuse this name? It's not a `global` class that could be referenced by some one else who must be sure that I do not change the semantics behind an interface.
2. What is this not allowed when I can change the code (therefore
   semantics) from each minor Patch release?
3. Is this worth a new entry in the IdeaExchange?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that we could undelete classes that we deletes in already uploaded version was not a feature but a bug. After some days of intensive communication Salesforce.com support could reproduce it and fix the [severe problems we ran into due to this platform bug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56112/customer-org-corrupted-public-class-deleted-in-1-2-magically-gets-deprecated-in).

Comment: Did you ever hear back on this, were you able to reuse the class again?

Comment: @ShaikhMohdNadeem: Support told me this is intended behavior and I indeed was never able to reuse such classes.

Comment: :(  This makes me think if the correct way to deprecate the class would be to add the deprecated annotation and throw "This class is deprecated" exception in its methods, in case the class may turn out to be useful in future?